# What Indexes do I need to add?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to speed this query up and I have all the indexes/foreign keys I need except for one last part.

Looking at the `type` column I can see that `pb` is looking at `all` records, which I need to rectify.

I am wondering if you could help me figure out what other indexes/FK I need, and of course if you have any general pointers please do let me know.

Query:

```
  explain SELECT  
           *
        FROM `Publish` AS pb
        LEFT JOIN Positions AS p ON pb.`Position_ID` = p.`Position_ID`
        LEFT JOIN PositionDetails AS pd ON pb.PositionDetail_ID = pd.PositionDetail_ID
        LEFT JOIN Posts AS ps ON pb.`Post_ID` = ps.`Post_ID`
        
        INNER JOIN Users AS u ON pb.`User_ID` = u.`User_ID`
        
        LEFT JOIN PublishWatch AS pw ON (p.`Position_ID` = pw.`Position_ID`  OR ps.Post_ID = pw.Post_ID ) AND   1=pw.`User_ID`
        
        LEFT JOIN UserFollow AS uf ON pb.User_ID = uf.FollowUser_ID AND  1=  uf.`User_ID` 
     
        ORDER BY pb.Published desc
        limit 0,50
```

Explain Output:

[image]

Full, original Query (in php):

```
$StrategiesWhere1 = "";

if (isset($_POST["Strategies"]) && sizeof($_POST["Strategies"]) > 0) {
    $in1 = "";
    $whereIn = [];
    foreach ($_POST["Strategies"] as $i => $item) {
        $key1 = ":1id" . $i;
        $param[$key1] = $item; // collecting values into key-value array
        array_push($whereIn, $key1);
    }

    $StrategiesWhere1 = "AND p.PositionType_ID in (" . implode(",", $whereIn) . ")";
}

$sql = "SELECT  
            pb.User_ID AS USERID,

            p.*,
            p.CommentCount as PositionCommentCount,
            p.WatchCount as PositionWatchCount,

            n.Note,

            pt.Strategy,
            pt.isUndefinedRisk,

            a.Name,
            
            u.Display,
            u.AllPosts as UserAllPosts,
            u.AllPositions as UserAllPositions,
            u.AllComments as UserAllComments,
            u.isPro,
            u.isSupporter,

            ps.*,
            ps.CommentCount as PostCommentCount,
            ps.WatchCount as PostWatchCount,
            
            pb.Published,
            pb.Publish_ID,

            pw.PublishWatch_ID,
            
            pw.AllComments AS PublishWatchAllComments,

            pd.isClosing,
            pd.isOpening,
            pd.Price,

            uf.AllComments AS UserFollowAllComments,
            uf.FollowUser_ID,
            uf.UserFollow_ID
        FROM `Publish` AS pb
        LEFT JOIN Positions AS p ON pb.`Position_ID` = p.`Position_ID`
        LEFT JOIN PositionDetails AS pd ON pb.PositionDetail_ID = pd.PositionDetail_ID
        LEFT JOIN Posts AS ps ON pb.`Post_ID` = ps.`Post_ID`
        LEFT JOIN PositionTypes AS pt ON p.`PositionType_ID` = pt.`PositionType_ID`
        LEFT JOIN Accounts AS a ON p.`Account_ID` = a.`Account_ID`
        INNER JOIN Users AS u ON pb.`User_ID` = u.`User_ID`
        LEFT JOIN Notes AS n ON p.`LastestNote_ID` = n.`Note_ID`
        
        LEFT JOIN PublishWatch AS pw ON (pb.`Position_ID` = pw.`Position_ID`  OR pb.Post_ID = pw.Post_ID ) AND  :User_ID4 = pw.`User_ID` 
        
        LEFT JOIN UserFollow AS uf ON pb.User_ID = uf.FollowUser_ID AND    :User_ID5 = uf.`User_ID`
        WHERE
      
        
            (
                (
                    :Type1 in ('Both','Only Positions') 
                    AND p.`Position_ID` IS NOT NULL 
                    AND p.`Security` LIKE :Security 
                    " . $StrategiesWhere1 . "
                ) 
                OR
                (
                    p.`Position_ID` IS NULL 
                )
            )
            -- Posts Filters
            AND  
            (
                (
                    :Type2 in ('Both','Only Posts') 
                    AND ps.Post_ID IS NOT NULL 
                    AND (
                        ps.Post like :PostContains1 
                        OR ps.Subject like :PostContains2
                    )
                    OR
                    (
                        ps.Post_ID IS NULL
                    )
                )
            )
            -- User Display name
            AND
            (
                (
                    :Display1 != ''
                    AND u.Display = :Display2
                )
                OR
                (
                    :Display3 = ''
                )
            )
            -- Account
            AND
            (
                (
                    :Account1 != ''
                    AND a.Name = :Account2
                )
                OR
                (
                    :Account3 = ''
                )
            )
            -- Only Watching 
            AND
            (
                (
                    :Watching1 = 'Both'
                )
                OR
                (
                    :Watching2 = 'Only Watched'
                    AND pw.PublishWatch_ID IS NOT NULL
                )
                OR
                (
                    :Watching3 = 'Only Unwatched'
                    AND pw.PublishWatch_ID IS NULL
                )
            )
            
            -- Pro Limitations
            AND
               (
                   (
                       -- If this is pro they get everything
                       :isPro1 = 1
                   )
                   OR 
                   (
                       -- Or if this isnt me
                       u.User_ID != 1
                   )
                   OR
                   (
                       -- If this is me and its on the small account  
                       -- or a post                      
                       u.User_ID = 1
                       AND 
                       ( a.Account_ID = 1
                           OR
                       pb.Position_ID is null)
                   )
                   OR 
                   (
                       -- If this is not pro and this is my publish and it isnt the small account or post
                       -- only show closing trade
                       u.User_ID = 1
                       AND a.Account_ID != 1
                       AND p.Closed is not null
                   )
               )
        ORDER BY pb.Published desc
        limit :Offset,:Count;
        ";
```

Updated explain with keys provided by Thorsten:

[image: Updated Explain]

Comment: The query looks weird. Is this generated? In that case the query could be completely different when generated with other parameters? As is, many of the conditions can be removed (e.g. because `"Both" = 'Both'` and `"" = ''`). (You should stick to standard single quotes by the way and not use double quotes for string literals.) On first glance it doesn't look like any indexes apart from indexes on primary and foreign keys can be of much help here. But then, maybe some conditions should be moved to the  `ON` clauses. In that case indexes could include the related columns.

Comment: This is written by hand, but where you see the both =both etc there are variables there. I took query from code, and replaced variables with hard coded values so that I can run repeatedly, and use explain. That also is the reason for the double quotes/ mixing quotes.

Comment: You should then change this back to bind variables, so we see what you are actually comparing. What is `"" = ''`? Are you comparing two bind variables? One column with one bind variable? Two columns? Please edit your request to show the real query.

Comment: I got the pw table now with a missing FK. As for the ''='' that occurs when I sending in a variable = ''. So, this query is a general select, that allows for filter parameters to be sent in. So if a variable is passed in, do x,y, or z depending on its value. Ill reduce the query in the question to only pertain to to the 'pb' pieces as that is the last index I need to get working.

Comment: There, I've simplified the query to just the relevant parts that are giving me the issue. I think I have all the keys/index I need, but am unable to get the last bit to be optimized.

Comment: Okay. Make sure to have an index on `publishwatch(user_id, position_id, post_id)`. For `userfollow` I'd provide two indexes, one on `userfollow(user_id, followuser_id)` and one on `userfollow(followuser_id, user_id)`. Thus the DBMS can decide how to best approach the join.

Comment: You may also want to add columns to existing indexes (or create new indexes on the combined columns), based on criteria hidden in your WHERE clause, which you have removed from your request. Without seeing the **original query**, we cannot give you any justified advice.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I've included the full original (in php) query, as well as the updated explain. Query is already much better, but of course always open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would put the join conditions on `Positions` and `Posts` to their `ON` clauses where they belong:

```
LEFT JOIN Positions AS p ON pb.Position_ID = p.Position_ID
                         AND :Type1 in ('Both', 'Only Positions') 
                         AND p.Security LIKE :Security 
                         " . $StrategiesWhere1 . "

LEFT JOIN Posts AS ps ON pb.Post_ID = ps.Post_ID
                      AND :Type2 in ('Both', 'Only Posts') 
                      AND 
                      (
                        ps.Post like :PostContains1 
                        OR
                        ps.Subject like :PostContains2
                      )
```

One thing that looks a bit suspicious to me: You select `Positions` and `PositionDetails`, but the two don't seem related. From the table names I would expect you only wanted `PositionDetails` with the same `Position_ID` as `Positions`, but maybe `PositionDetails` doesn't have a `Position_ID`. This may be an issue or not, and if it is, I am not sure whether this really is an issue with the query or rather with the data model.

As to performance; this

```
ORDER BY pb.Published desc
limit :Offset,:Count;
```

can be quite slow. What this does is get the whole result set (I don't know whether this is tens, hundreds, or thousands of rows in your case) then sort the complete set to get the desired subset. It doesn't matter, if you want the first 50 rows or the second 50 rows or the last fifty rows; the DBMS will always have to select the full dataset and sort it in order to return the desired rows.

All your joins join just one table row each to a `Publish` row, except for `PublishWatch` where the same user can watch both the position and post, in which case you would get two result rows for one `Publish` row instead of only one. So, instead of requesting the next fifty rows, you may request the next fifty `Published` dates/times:

```
WHERE pb.Published > :last_max_published
ORDER BY pb.Published desc
limit :Count;
```

Thus you would always only look at the remaining rows and not have to sort all rows that you already dealt with.

As to indexes you can try the following. Some of them are covering indexes, i.e. they contain all columns used in the query. This means that if the DBMS uses these indexes, it doesn't have to read the table. You can provide all these indexes, then check which ones are used and then delete the others.

```
CREATE INDEX idx01 ON Users(Display, User_ID);
CREATE INDEX idx02 ON Accounts(Name, User_ID, Account_ID);
CREATE INDEX idx03 ON Positions(Position_ID, Closed);
CREATE INDEX idx04 ON PublishWatch(User_ID, Position_ID, Post_ID, PublishWatch_ID, AllComments);
CREATE INDEX idx05 ON UserFollow(User_ID, FollowUser_ID);
CREATE INDEX idx06 ON UserFollow(FollowUser_ID, User_ID);
CREATE INDEX idx07 ON Positions(Position_ID, Security);
CREATE INDEX idx08 ON Posts(Post_ID, Post, Subject);
CREATE INDEX idx09 ON Accounts(Account_ID, Name);
CREATE INDEX idx10 ON Notes(Note_ID, Note);
CREATE INDEX idx11 ON PositionTypes(PositionType_ID, isUndefinedRisk, Strategy);
CREATE INDEX idx12 ON Publish(Published);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend learning how to read the **execution plans** for your database platform. When troubleshooting a query, this is a decent place to start. Execution plans typically share what indexes may help optimize the query. However be careful not to just add indexes though as this can effect the performance of other queries unintentionally.

A couple tips for your current query:

- SELECT only the columns that you need in your output - You have SELECT `*` for multiple tables which consumes resources to return.
- Use the minimum number of joins necessary - A (not hard fast rule) that I use is to keep the number of joins to <= 3 per query. This has always served me well.
- Write readable SQL to assist with code maintainability - Your WHERE clause is difficult to quickly read and understand. By writing cleanly you will thank yourself 6 months from now when you (or others) have to read your query again.

Best wishes!